# Missing android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils (function formatNumber) in Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, telephony, delphi-10-seattle

I need some functions from **Android public class android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils** in Delphi.

Specifically, it is a function **formatNumber(String phoneNumber, String defaultCountryIso)**.

Someone advise me how to solve this problem?

Comment: I do not know (or rather do not understand) why get evaluation questions '-' without a single comment ...

Comment: Using Java libraries is covered extensively in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_Java_Libraries_in_Your_RAD_Studio_Android_Apps), and the IDE even includes tools to help you do so. The [Telephony library](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_the_Built-in_RAD_Studio_Java_Libraries_for_Android) is already provided for you as part of the Android support. What specific part of that are you having difficulties with?

Comment: I'm a newbie in Delphi (for Android).
Could you somehow illustrate some advice?
I can use library Androidapi.JNI.Telephony, but I can not find a sub-library PhoneNumberUtils (in Androidapi.JNI.Telephony).

Comment: It's simply - use TJPhoneNumberUtils.JavaClass.formatNumber()

Comment: The *sublibrary* is a *class* (`TJPhoneNumberUtils`) located in the `Androidapi.JNI.Telephony` unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **TJPhoneNumberUtils.JavaClass.formatNumber()**.

All other function used in Android.Telephony.PhoneNumberUtils you can find in TJPhoneNumberUtils.JavaClass